# How do I install matplotlib dependencies?

Tags: software-installation, python, pip, matplotlib

How can I easily install all the non-Python dependencies I require before I can `pip install matplotlib`?

Comment: You don't just need the run-time dependencies to install the package with Pip. You need the *build*-dependencies (as you state in your answer) because Pip will build (parts of) the Python module from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy way to install all non-Python dependencies before doing a pip installation:

1. Install dependencies of the system version – this does not install the system version itself.

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
   ```
2. Enter your virtualenv as usual (you may use a different tool to do this):

   ```
   pew workon your_virtualenv
   ```
3. Install `matplotlib` (and all python dependencies like `numpy`) from `pypi`:

   ```
   pip install matplotlib
   ```

Note this installs *all* dependencies (for *all* `matplotlib` components, including optional components that you may not use). The benefit is: easy installation, future-proofing. The cost is: download time/bandwidth. This method doesn't account for: brand new dependencies (if pip version > system version and very new dependencies have been introduced) — in this case you'll need to do it the traditional way (find what's breaking and consult documentation/support).

References: http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#building-on-linux

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get build-dep` for both `python-matplotlib` and `python3-matplotlib` but I it only seems to work for python2. i.e. `ìmport wx` returns an error in python3. Am I missing something obvious? Should I post a new question?

Comment: I think a new question with your specific steps, but feel free to come back and update this answer if there's a general step missing

Comment: Thanks, it's already done here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034442/build-matplotlib-dependencies-for-both-python2-and-python3