# Build matplotlib dependencies for both python2 and python3

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, python, dependencies, matplotlib

I would like to have various virtual environments in my computer, some of them running python 2.7 and others with python3, and some of them must have full matplotlib support, which is achieved with `--system-syte-packages` when creating the virtual environment (see [matplotlib faqs](https://matplotlib.org/faq/virtualenv_faq.html)).

Therefore, I need to biuld the dependencies of matplotlib for both python versions. I started with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

Which installed everything properly, and then I tried to run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-matplotlib
```

Which did nothing, it only printed the following messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'matplotlib' as source package instead of 'python3-matplotlib'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
```

How can this be solved? Both a `pip` or `apt-get` related solutions are welcome.

### EDIT:

I can install matplotlib in a python3 virtual environment without any problem, however, it does not support many of the backends. For instance:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('GTK')
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oriol/venvs/pic_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 17, in <module>
    import gobject
ImportError: No module named 'gobject'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/oriol/venvs/pic_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/oriol/venvs/pic_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/home/oriol/venvs/pic_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 21, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.")
ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
```

Even though `pip freeze` inside the virtual environment includes `pygobject==3.20.0`. I thought that this `pygobject` may be the python2 one, however, the `sys.path` in the virtual environment is:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/oriol/venvs/pic_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Comment: what happens when you try to create a python3 virtualenv and install matplotlib there? could it be that it works (and you don't need any additional packages)?

Comment: do you know which 6 packages aren't upgraded (or is that unrelated)?

Comment: @d3vid I have updated the question to answer your first question. About the 2nd question, I have no idea what packages are this 6. How can I see them?

Comment: this looks to me like matplotlib is installing correctly, and you have a different dependency issue - can you confirm it works with a simpler backend?

Comment: for GTK/pygobject you need a different dependency that hooks into your system-level gtk files from within the virtualenv - I'm afraid I don't recall the name right now

Comment: Yes, I have no problem installing matplotlib, either in python2 or python3. My question is, _if possible_, about building the dependencies (all of them, to use the different backends) in both pythons.

Comment: TK can be used from within a virtual environment without the `--system-site-packages`